# Binding two actions to the same event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I would like to bind two events together.

Right now my set up is I bind all mouse actions that I need to a canvas then call a wrapper function that makes mouse position relative to the canvas.  The wrapper function then calls the correct action in an internal function.  I would also like to bind the `touchstart` `touchmove` and `touchend`

Here is an example structure of what I have:

```
$('canvas').bind('mousedown mousemove mouseup', ev_canvas);
function ev_canvas (e) {
    var pos = findPos(this);
    e._x = e.pageX - pos.x;
    e._y = e.pageY - pos.y;

    var func = tool[e.type];
    if (func) {
        func(e);
    }
}

tools.pen = function () {
    tool.mousedown = function (e) {
        //Stuff to do
    };

    tool.mousemove = function (e) {
        //Stuff to do
    };

    tool.mouseup = function (e) {
        //Stuff to do
    };
}
```

This calls the correct tool and then calls the mouse(up|down|move) function depending on the action.

Is there a way to bind the touch actions to those so it can call one or the other with out copy and pasting a bunch of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a mapping table - eventName : callbackName. Here is a sample

```
var functionMappings = { 
   mousemove: "mousemove",
   touchmove: "mousemove",
   mousedown: "mousedown",
   touchstart: "mousedown",
   mouseup: "mouseup",
   touchend: "mouseup"
};

var func = tool[functionMappings[e.type]];

if (func) {
   func(e);
}
```